# Apples 3D Touch Peek Functionality Restrictions

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I am looking in the newly announced 3D Touch to be released in the next set of apple phones. I see a great use case for this in and app that I have in development however when looking up the feature (https://developer.apple.com/ios/3d-touch/) I still cannot get a good feel for what Human Interface Restrictions may be in place for this type of feature.

If there is someone out there who understands how this 3D Touch works. Will it be possible (and permitted) to develop a Modal pop-up `UITableView` that would appear when 3D Touch force press is made on an item within the app? I am thinking something similar to the "Quick Actions" they have for the home screen but within my app.

Currently in the app, the user clicks on the item, sees its details page, and then its a "set" button to set it to a certain position a daily slot. I was thinking it would be much easier if the user could skip the details screen all together and have a force touch bring up a modal popup with a list of days for them to choose allowing them to set the item faster.

I am wondering if this would be in violation of the Human Interface Guidelines or would cause any trouble when submitting the app?

Comment: Did you check that [Adopting 3D Touch on iPhone](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/Adopting3DTouchOniPhone/) ?

Comment: That seems like what I was looking for. Hopefully it will shine some light on the question. Thanks.

Comment: What you want to know actually ?

Comment: Currently in the app, the user clicks on the item, sees its details page, and then its a "set" button to set it to a certain position a daily slot. I was thinking it would be much easier if the user could skip the details screen all together and have a force touch bring up a modal popup with a list of days for them to choose allowing them to set the item faster.

Comment: Do you asking for Peek and Pop in 3D Touch? Please update your question with your description.

Comment: There are APIs available to adopt the 3D Touch [3D Touch APIs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/Adopting3DTouchOniPhone/3DTouchAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016543-CH4-SW1)